# Document manager

Tags: linux, file-management, information-management

I'm looking for a powerful document manager application. Example applications are: **Macjournal** or **DevonThink** but they're available for Mac OS only.
I've a Linux Elementary Juno installed.

The features I'm looking for are:

- auto-tagging
- support for multiple file types (txt, rtf, PDF, calc tables, presentation, pictures, movies, various code-languages)
- to study, research, organize files effortlessly
- robustness is also important when you deal with tons of files

The beauty of document manager is they collect everything relevant to you only and documents are immediately displayed and editable.

Please no file manager applications, as they encourage procrastination. Too technical, with hundreds of paths and files that stack over time in disorganized way, - copying between different paths is no workflow. Just an old storage method.

#### Update

So far I found **Tellico** and **Pile**, but both create just references to the files on disk and open originals within their default applications. We're closer but I'm sorry this isn't yet useful.

Answer (score 1):

[Trilium](https://github.com/zadam/trilium) seems to be a better solution that's more along the lines of DEVONthink and very robust.

Answer (score 0):

Give [Zim](https://www.zim-wiki.org/downloads.html) a try. I’m not sure if it works in elementary OS, which I wouldn’t recommend to anyone, but for sure it works in GNOME Ubuntu.

Comment: Zim is a text editor and links documents each other. I need a tool able to *import, view and edit* various file formats. (txt, rtf, PDF, calc tables, presentation, pictures, movies, various code-languages )